# PiFace & asyncio: loop won't stop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a PiFace board stacked onto my Raspberry Pi and want to quit my python program when I press button 3. I therefore attach an interrupt listener to this button and call loop.stop() in the callback, but my loop won't stop. It is as if my commands are ignored.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pifacedigitalio as piface
import asyncio
import time

QUIT_DETECT = 3

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
counter = 0

def onQuit(event):
    # Doesn't stop
    global loop
    loop.stop()
    print(loop)

    # Does change
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter)

piface.init()

listener = piface.InputEventListener()
listener.register(QUIT_DETECT, piface.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, onQuit)
listener.activate()

loop.run_forever()

loop.close()
listener.deactivate()
piface.deinit()
```

The output is:

```
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
1
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
2
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
3
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
4
```

So `counter` is increased on each press, but `loop` just won't take my stop call. Can anyone tell me how to stop the loop? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure asyncio is supposed to run on raspberry-pi? (maybe it's not raspberry-py for a reason :D)

Comment: @vlad-ardelean I suppose so. Why not? I'll try a workaround with a `Barrier` object in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have some coroutines running and do some work, because in this snippet there is no need for asyncio, it's just missused for blocking...

Nevertheless I'm quite sure you have a **threading problem**.

Looking on gitHub in the modules:

```
piface.InputEventListener()
```

dreives from pifacecommon.interrupts.PortEventListener

```
class InputEventListener(pifacecommon.interrupts.PortEventListener):
```

[github pifacedigitalio](https://github.com/piface/pifacedigitalio/blob/master/pifacedigitalio/core.py)

PortEventListener uses Threading and Multiprocessing

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
[....]
class PortEventListener(object):
"""Listens for port events and calls the registered functions.
>>> def print_flag(event):
...     print(event.interrupt_flag)
...
>>> port = pifacecommon.mcp23s17.GPIOA
>>> listener = pifacecommon.interrupts.PortEventListener(port)
>>> listener.register(0, pifacecommon.interrupts.IODIR_ON, print_flag)
>>> listener.activate()
"""

TERMINATE_SIGNAL = "astalavista"

def __init__(self, port, chip, return_after_kbdint=True, daemon=False):
    self.port = port
    self.chip = chip
    self.pin_function_maps = list()
    self.event_queue = EventQueue(self.pin_function_maps)
    self.detector = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=watch_port_events,
        args=(
            self.port,
            self.chip,
            self.pin_function_maps,
            self.event_queue,
            return_after_kbdint))
    self.detector.daemon = daemon
    self.dispatcher = threading.Thread(
        target=handle_events,
        args=(
            self.pin_function_maps,
            self.event_queue,
            _event_matches_pin_function_map,
            PortEventListener.TERMINATE_SIGNAL))
    self.dispatcher.daemon = daemon
```

[github pifacecommon](https://github.com/piface/pifacecommon/blob/master/pifacecommon/interrupts.py)

seems to run in a different Thread and call's you back. Obviously the stop doesn't reach the asyncio.loop in main thread.

---

Agree, so far?

Ideally you should use either threading or async programming in one thread.

Nevertheless I expect that it will work to handover the loop reference instead of using it global:
    def onQuit(loop):

```
listener.register(QUIT_DETECT, piface.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, onQuit(loop))
```

or
    from functools import partial
    listener.register(QUIT_DETECT, piface.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, partial(onQuit, loop))

---

Have you tried to re-get the loop instead of global usage in onQuit?
   asyncio.get_event_loop()

Have fun
Danny